# How to selected a range cells with mouse in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a table with reactjs. So I want to when a user clicks a cell and hold moves to another cell. The cells between have to highlight. I do it with DOM selector.
And I think it a not the right way to react. So how I can do it without DOM SELECTOR

Here my code with dom select:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import './Style.css';

export default function Table() {
    const [cell, setCell] = useState([]);
    let div = [];

    let selecting, start, end;

    let beginSelection = i => {
        selecting = true;
        start = i;
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let endSelection = (i = end) => {
        selecting = false;
        updateSelection(i);
    };

    let updateSelection = i => {
        if (selecting)
            end = i;
        [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].forEach((span, i) =>
            span.classList.toggle('selected', i >= start && i <= end || i >= end && i <= start));
    };



    for(let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        let a = <span key={i} onMouseDown={()=>beginSelection(i)} onMouseUp={()=>endSelection(i)} onMouseMove={()=>updateSelection(i)}>{i}</span>;

        div.push(a);
        cell.push(a);
    }


    return div;
}
```

here is my demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Kalipts/hover
please help. Thanks

Comment: https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/demos/Grid/Selection/MultipleSelection/react

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using state & className for cell element

`className={
          (end <= i && i <= start) || (start <= i && i <= end) ? "selected" : ""
        }`

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-driscoll-r8649